# CRC doesn't return expected value

Tags: python, math, byte, protocols, crc

I have some technical documentation and try to replicate the given CRC algorithm in python. However I don't get the correct results. How do I have to tweak my algo to match the docs?

This is the documentation:

[image]

And this is my code:

```
data1 = b'\0x01\0x04\0x00\0x0b\0x00\0x01'
data2 = b'\0x01\0x03\0x00\0x65\0x00\0x01'


def crc16(data : bytearray):
    length = len(data)
    crc = 0xffff
    for i in range(0, length):
        crc ^= data[i]
        for j in range(0,8):
            if (crc & 0x01):
                crc =(crc >> 1) ^ 0xa001
            else:
                crc = crc >> 1
    return crc

print(crc16(data1).to_bytes(2, 'big'))
print(crc16(data2).to_bytes(2, 'big'))
```

Here are some examples for the documentation:
[image]
[image]

Here are my results:

```
b'\xc9Y'
b'\xd4\xd1'
```

Comment: Rather than loop over the length of data, it would be a tad more idiomatic, general, and clean to loop directly over the elements, e.g. `for d in data: crc ^= d ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input data is wrong. The first one should be `b'\x01\x04\x00\x0b\x00\x01'` for example. The first string as written by you has `'\0'` (a null character), followed by the literal characters `'x04'`, and so on. You can check this by printing the strings.

Once this is corrected your code appears to give the correct results.

As a minor note, your type information for the `data` parameter says it takes a `bytearray` but you're actually passing it `bytes`.

Comment: Correct, as documented in [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) `bytes` would be correct but not `bytearray`: *As a shorthand for this type, bytes can be used to annotate arguments of any of the types mentioned above.*

Comment: Thanks. it worked. I also had to replace 'big' with 'little'.